# how to calculate $\phi (625)$? Eulers's Totient

Tags: congruences, totient-function

euler's totient relies on primes, and coprimes in order to determine $\phi (n)$ but 625 is not the product of any 2 primes, and none of its factors are coprimes so how would you determine $\phi (625)$?

Comment: $625=5^4$, what do you mean it doesn't contain any primes?

Comment: I mean that 625 is not the product of 2 distinct primes.

Comment: Have you done any research?

Answer (score 3):

From the MathWorld page on [Euler's totient function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TotientFunction.html):

> If $m = p^{\alpha}$ is a power of a prime, then the numbers that have a common factor with $m$ are the multiples of $p$: $p$, $2p$, ..., $p^{\alpha-1}p$. There are $p^{\alpha-1}$ of these multiples, so the number of factors  relatively prime to $p^{\alpha}$ is $$\phi(p^{\alpha}) = p^{\alpha}-p^{\alpha-1} = p^{\alpha-1}(p-1)$$

Let $p = 5$ and $\alpha = 4$ and you get $\phi(625) = 125\cdot 4 = 500$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\phi(625)=500$$

There are many ways to calculate this. Several are detailed on [Wolfram *MathWorld*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TotientFunction.html); just pick your poison.