# How to calculate remainder using Fermat's Little Theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I want calculate remainder when $2^{1000}$ is divided by $5^{4}$
Can I calculate it using Fermat's Little Theorem?

Comment: Hint: $a^{\varphi(m)} \equiv 1 \pmod {m}$

Comment: how can I  calculate pi of $5^{4}$?

Comment: It is too general question to ask here. Have you tried finding an answer from google? [See this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#:~:text=%2C%20and%20may%20also%20be%20called,to%20as%20totatives%20of%20n.)

Comment: $\phi(p^k)=(p-1)\cdot p^{k-1}$

Answer (score 2):

A very useful concept here is **Euler totient function**.

We denote $\varphi(m) : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ an arithmetical function. $\varphi(m)$ means the number of positive integers which are coprime to $n$. This function has some useful and interesting properties like these:

1. **Incomplete multiplicity.** For $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$, with $(m, n) = 1$, $\varphi(m) \cdot \varphi(n) = \varphi(mn)$.
2. **Euler's product formula.** If $m$ is an integer, we can calculate
   $$\varphi(n) = n \prod_{p \ | \ n} \left(1 - \frac{1}{p}\right).$$
3. **Euler's product formula for prime powers.** If $p$ is a prime number and $k$ a positive integer, we can calculate
   $$\varphi(p^k) = p^k \left(1 - \frac{1}{p}\right).$$
4. **Gauss's formula.** If $n$ is a natural number, this formula states that
   $$\sum_{d \ | \ n} \varphi(d) = n.$$
5. **Euler's theorem.** If $a$ is an integer and $m$ a natural number, then
   $$a^{\varphi(m)} \equiv 1 \ (\text{mod} \ m).$$
   From this theorem derives directly Fermat's little theorem, with the only mention that for a prime number $p$, $\varphi(p) = p - 1$, obviously by definition of $\varphi$-function.

All this being known about this interesting number theory application, the problem looks much more easy. We have, by Euler's theorem
$$2^{\varphi(5^4)} \equiv 1 \ (\text{mod} \ 5^4).$$

But, by Euler's product formula for prime powers,
$$\varphi(5^4) = 5^4 \cdot \frac{4}{5} = 125 \cdot 4 = 500.$$

So
$$2^{500} \equiv 1 \ (\text{mod} \ 5^4),$$

meaning that
$$2^{1000} \equiv (2^{500})^2 \equiv 1 \ (\text{mod} \ 5^4)$$

And this finishes our computation using Euler's theorem. It doesn't look like Fermat may have any link in this exercise/problem.

Sources:

[1]. https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Euler%27s_totient_function

[2]. [how to calculate $\phi (625)$? Eulers's Totient](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2517300/how-to-calculate-phi-625-eulerss-totient)

Comment: OP asked for $2^{1000}$, not $2^{2000}$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Modified now.